# How to upload file from google drive to server using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I want to upload file from google drive to S3 server.Could you please share me the idea and suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
$fileId = '0BwwA4oUTeiV1UVNwOHItT0xfa2M';
$response = $driveService->files->get($fileId, array(
'alt' => 'media'));
$content = $response->getBody()->getContents();
```

This is the code for downloading a file from google drive. 
Ref: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads

Thus you need to upload it to s3 using AWS SDK

```
use Aws\Common\Exception\MultipartUploadException;
use Aws\S3\Model\MultipartUpload\UploadBuilder;
$uploader = UploadBuilder::newInstance()
    ->setClient($client)
    ->setSource('/path/to/large/file.mov')
    ->setBucket('mybucket')
    ->setKey('my-object-key')
    ->setOption('Metadata', array('Foo' => 'Bar'))
    ->setOption('CacheControl', 'max-age=3600')
    ->build();

// Perform the upload. You can abort the upload if something goes wrong
try {
    $uploader->upload();
    echo "Upload complete.\n";
} catch (MultipartUploadException $e) {
    $uploader->abort();
    echo "Upload failed.\n";
}
```

Ref: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/service-s3.html#uploading-large-files-using-multipart-uploads